# How much UV does a hydrogen flame emit?

Tags: hydrogen, combustion

A hydrogen flame is invisible but emits ultraviolet (and infrared) radiation. How much UV does a hydrogen flame emit for a given reactant flow or a given heating power? Could a hydrogen flame be used as a useful UV light source? (Or if not, could other chemical reactions be used as such?)

In trying to google this I found lots of information on UV flame detectors, but not something answering this question.

Comment: found this on google https://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/tb/techbriefs/physical-sciences/20322 not much in the uv at 390, most in the IR.

Comment: Use a [Limelight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limelight). This is simply lime, i.e., calcium oxide, intensely heated with a hydrogen and oxygen flame. I do not have a spectrum available, but it will definitely produce some UV along with very intense white light. Or just burn magnesium, titanium, zirconium, etc. Lots of UV that is dangerous to the eyes: eye protection, i.e., welder’s goggles or the like, is essential.